# How to check message existing in Slack?

Tags: bots, slack-api, slack

I making a Slack bot based on BotKit. Bot observes certain Slack messages and creates corresponding entities in a database. Entities are associated with these messages.

If somebody removed a message, Slack send RTM event [message_deleted](https://api.slack.com/events/message/message_deleted) and I can hook this event and clean all entities associated with deleted message.

My problem is messages removed when bot-server is stopped for maintenance. Bot lost message_deleted event.

How can I get messages, that being removed when the bot server was stopped?

Comment: One of the decision - to try to add reaction to a message. If Slack API is returned error then message is unavailable (possible deleted)

Comment: Instead of adding a reaction (which has a side effect of actually adding the reaction), you might consider using [`reactions.get`](https://api.slack.com/methods/reactions.get) instead and look for a `message_not_found` error.

Comment: thanks, I have not seen this method in the documentation :)